# Swift sending 'map' as query parameter

Tags: swift, spring

This is a simple question but I can't find out how to do this. I have a Java backend that looks as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/batch", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<EventElasticsearchDTO> getBatch(
        @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = false, defaultValue = "10") Integer pageSize,
        @RequestParam(value = "paginationToken", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer paginationToken,
        @RequestParam(value = "lat") Double latitude,
        @RequestParam(value = "long") Double longitude,
        @RequestParam Map<String, String> queryOptions) throws IOException {...}
```

My question is, in Swift, how do I send the **queryOptions** param. Otherwise put, if my url looks like this: `https://api.example.net/api/event/batch?paginationToken=5&long=-165.0312186&lat=45.33233141`, what should it appear as when I add queryOptions?

I am **already using URLQueryComponents. I want to know how to send a map using URLQueryComponents.**

```
if let queryParams = queryParams {
  components.queryItems = queryParams.map { (key, value) -> URLQueryItem in
    URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value)
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked `URLComponents` and `URLQueryItems`

Comment: What do you want to send as `queryOptions` ?

Comment: say I just want to send ["maxItems" : "1000000"]

Comment: Seems you have the code for that. What is your question? Is the code not behaving as you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map<String, String> queryOptions` is way used to hold all parameter**s** as a `Map`. You just need to send an extra parameter and the server side will put it into `queryOptions` with its name:

```
//`queryParams` may be a parameter to some method, here just to show how to do it...
let queryParams: [String: String]? = [
    "paginationToken": "5",
    "long": "-165.0312186",
    "lat": "45.33233141",
    "maxItems": "1000000", //<- Just add it
]

if let queryParams = queryParams {
    components.queryItems = queryParams.map { (key, value) -> URLQueryItem in
        URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value)
    }
}
```

In your server side, all parameters other than named parameters are put into `queryOptions`.